# Oracle error using "in"

Tags: sql, oracle

Why do I have an error in this query?

***My request:***

```
SELECT * FROM CURVES c WHERE c.TYPE_CURVES in ({0}, {10}, {20}, {30})
```

***Error:***

> ORA-00911 invalid character

Comment: What's exactly the purpose of that curly-braces syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it should read:

```
SELECT * FROM CURVES c WHERE c.TYPE_CURVES in (0)
```

[This](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/in.php) is a good site for understanding it.

**EDIT**

Adding multiple pieces of data...

```
SELECT * FROM CURVES c WHERE c.TYPE_CURVES in (0,20,30,40)
```

Or as strings...

```
SELECT * FROM CURVES c WHERE c.TYPE_CURVES in ('0','20','30','40')
```